# Incompatible types error when put ArrayList as value to a map

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, compiler-errors, maps

I am getting the list if it already exists and adding an element to it.

**Code snippet:**

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = new TreeMap<>(Collections.reverseOrder());
int n = sc.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    int factor = 0;
    int num = sc.nextInt();
    for (int j = 1; j <= num; j++)
      if (num % j == 0) factor++;  //just getting factor count of each input

    map.put(factor, map.getOrDefault(factor, new ArrayList<>()).add(num)); // error line
```

**Error details:**

> error: incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to List

***How to solve this trouble?***

Comment: Did you intend `map.put(factor, map.getOrDefault(factor, new ArrayList<>())).add(num)`? (closing brackets mismatch)

Comment: no bracket missmatch im just getting the list if already exists or creating a new one

Comment: "*incompatible types: boolean cannot be converted to List*" ... since `.add` returns a `boolean` value and you have enclosed it as the value within the `put` operation where a `List` is required as the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [add()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add-E-) has `boolean` as return type. You can not put boolean value to map which have `List<Integer>` as a value.

You need to create **ArrayList** -> add an element to it first.

And only then put it to a map as a value:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(num);
map.put(factor, map.getOrDefault(factor, list));
```

From Java 9+, you could use `List.of()`:

```
map.put(factor, map.getOrDefault(factor, List.of(num)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error line creates a new ArrayList<>() even if a previous ArrayList is re-used so try:

```
List<Integer> list = map.get(factor);
if (list == null) {
   list = new ArrayList<>();
   map.put(factor, list);
}
list.add(num);
```

In java 9 List.of(num) is immutable so .add(num) to existing would fail, but in Java 8+ you can use this more concise definition which creates the new ArrayList only if needed:

```
var map = new TreeMap<Integer, List<Integer>>(Collections.reverseOrder());
...
map.computeIfAbsent(factor, ArrayList::new).add(num);
```